# WP_List_Table can't create filter link

Tags: wp-list-table

I create a List table by extending WP_List_Table and showing data from an array. The problem is when searching the URL it adds nonce & _wp_http_referer automatically and a weird structure like that.

fin.local/wp-admin/admin.php?page=fin-options&s=273372321&_wpnonce=d11043d6b4&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Dfin-options&paged=1

Also, there is a column called status. I want to make some filter links for the status value.

[image]

Comment: Is _wp_http_referer really a problem? What does it break?

Comment: This question could use some more detail, such as the code being used to create the List Table. Also, please limit posts to one question. The part about the status column should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: This is the example that I followed
[link](https://github.com/Veraxus/wp-list-table-example)